# Differences of the VectorTiles Example

Tags: openlayers, vector-tiles

I am new into implementing Maps into WebApps.
I have started to implement a simple VectorTile Map through OpenLayers and I found a different example to implement it.

First, we have the Workshop Page of OpenLayers
https://openlayers.org/workshop/en/vectortile/map.html
The first example is working, but I want to implement a style with Mapbox.
So I tried this further explanation:
https://openlayers.org/workshop/en/vectortile/bright.html
This is not working at all, it does not take the Style. Is it an old example?

So I have searched for another Examples.
And found this:
https://cloud.maptiler.com/maps/basic/openlayers
This is working with one map, but I want two maps and when I implement two cards, the second one is overlapping with the first style.

Do someone has a working example with their own server?

What I don't understand, why there are some example where we do not have to implement libraries like OL in the header and why there are example which says you just need some line of codes to implement a VectorTile Map with Mapbox, and others are using, for example, the "fetch" method and the format MVT.

The format MVT is for showing VectorTiles
from the workshop page it says:

```
const layer = new VectorTileLayer({
  source: new VectorTileSource({
    attributions: [
      '<a href="http://www.openmaptiles.org/" target="_blank">&copy; OpenMapTiles</a>',
      '<a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/about/" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
    ],
    format: new MVT(),
    url: `https://free-{1-3}.tilehosting.com/data/v3/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf.pict?key=${key}`,
    maxZoom: 14
  })
});
map.addLayer(layer);
```

Then it says, delete everything in the .js file and implement just

```
const map = apply('map-container', './data/bright.json');
```

This is not working because there is no reference to olms.js and we do not have a fetch method, so I really do not understand what they are talking about

Why we sometimes use fetch() method in VectorTiles and sometimes we can just skip it and use apply() method from olms.js?

I am very confused.

This is what I use at the moment, created a second map instance and the second map takes parts of styles of the first map.

```
var styleJson = 'https://maps.tilehosting.com/styles/basic/style.json?key=0CrAfR2pgm6V6hYu3CEj';
    var map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 0]),
        zoom: 1
      })
    });
olms.apply(map, styleJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look on the [Github repo](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/ol-mapbox-style#apply), the method apply return an ol.Map object and init a lot for you like it's describe in the Parameters.

So you have two solution, implementing you own solution to fecth your Vector Tiles and apply your own strategy for the styling, or use ol-mapbox-style to handle the Mapbox style and convert it for Ol specification.